# URL-encoding and -decoding a string in Python

Tags: python, urlencode

Is there a way to urlencode/urldecode a string in Python? I want to emphasize that I want a single string, not a `dict`. I know of the function that does that to a `dict`. I could easily construct out of it a function that does that for a string, but I'd rather not have to construct my own function. Does Python have this functionality built-in?

(Answers for both Python 2.7 and 3.3 would be appreciated.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the `urllib` module [(docs here)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html), in particular the `urllib.quote` and `urllib.unquote` functions.

Answer (score 2):

urllib.unquote will do the trick